# Insert row with max result of same table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (NULL, 45, 12, NOW(), SELECT MAX(current_price) + 1 FROM table)
```

I want to insert a row having the "current price" equal to the max price of the the same table plus 1.
I'm using `SELECT MAX(current_price) + 1 FROM table` to do this.

The problem is the it returns an error.
Can someone help?

Comment: What exactly the error is? Have you tried insert select from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use brackets around sub-query:

```
INSERT INTO table 
VALUES (NULL, 45, 12, NOW(), (SELECT MAX(current_price) + 1 FROM table));
```

Better way to do this:

```
INSERT INTO table 
SELECT NULL, 45, 12, NOW(), MAX(current_price) + 1 FROM table;
```

Comment: @eggyal I prefer the second method which is better. (`INSERT INTO .. SELECT`).